# mysql suddenly ignoring table indices for a time

Tags: mysql, database

On our mysql 5.1 server is an innodb table called which is central to our web application.  It has around 150,000 rows and far too many columns due to a bad implementation.

Lately we've been running a task that updates the table frequently (INSERT or UPDATE) once every few seconds.

When that task is running, the database will periodically (every 1 - 3 hours) become much slower to process client read requests.  During those times slow_log points to this table as the culprit and any request to it looks like it's doing a full table scan. Eventually, within 5-20 minutes it will work itself out and go back to processing normally.

My assumption is that the constant table updates are throwing mysql's query optimizer statistics out of whack every once in a while.  I don't know how to prove that or find a solution for it.

Can the following be the causes?

1. Too many secondary indices on the table (there are ~45, many
   unnecessary but will take time and care to prune away)
2. Bad configuration parameters (query_cache is ON and innodb_buffer is at 5G)
3. Mysql 5.1 is outdated and should be upgraded
4. The database server probably just needs more RAM/CPU to handle the load

I am more than happy to provide any additional information you might request in comments.

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN` statement give for the updates? But, the `query_cache` could very well be the villain here. If the `UPDATE` is big,it needs to clear the re-add it to the cache, that will always cost time.

Comment: Unfortunately EXPLAIN only works on SELECT statements for mysql 5.1.  There are some INSERTS that appear in the slow-log but those occur around the times when all SELECTS are slow so that could be more a symptom than a cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the following be the causes?
>
> Too many secondary indices on the table (there are ~45, many unnecessary but will take time and care to prune away)

Yes, if you are running a task witch does a lot of inserts/updates for sure having lots of indexes in that table will overload the sql engine. Take in account that for every insert/update, sql has to do the same insert for **each** index. Try to keep only those indexes that are really needed. And only if the amount of selects is bigger than the insert statements.

> Bad configuration parameters (query_cache is ON and innodb_buffer is
>   at 5G)

True, query_cache can help or not, it depends on the ram amount dedicated to it (**query_cache_size**) and the total ram amount your server have. The best is to assign it a small amount, check performance, increase the amount, again check if goes better and so on.
Other options like **key_buffer** (important! if you have so many indexes) can be decisive.

> Mysql 5.1 is outdated and should be upgraded

Well, of course it's important to upgrade and often boosts performance but I wouldn't expect this to resolve the problem.

> The database server probably just needs more RAM/CPU to handle the
>   load

We could say the same here, but I would priorize on the db design and optimizing queries.

Comment: This is probably as close to an answer we can get. On the good side, you have clear actions to take to solve the issue.

Comment: This is helpful and given me some direction.  I'm not completely convinced that the number of indexes/inserts is the only reason for this intermittent problem.  The task that updates the table is running throughout the day and we see a problem every 1 - 3 hours.  If INSERT overhead were the problem shouldn't this be a more constant issue?

Comment: For reference, the CPU is generally ~15% usage while the task runs, then steady 100% when the problem occurs.